# How to populate Salesforce Standard Lookup Fields on a Standard Page Using URL Parameters

Tags: apex, administration, developer-console, urlhacking

this is for Custom lookup fields : CF00Ni000000EpsgO_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
for standard lookup fields there is no id, So how to use standard lookup fields in url hacking

Comment: Standard lookup fields has also Ids. From record details page, right click and select view source and find the id.

Comment: I tried finding as u said but pasting the id in url, its not working